# Pulling & Splitting up database items in a listview

Tags: c#, sql, database, listview, listbox

I've written some code to simply pull database information from a compact SQL server (4.0). At the minute I've just seperated each item retrieved with a few spaces, but I'm wondering how I could pull each item and have it correspond to the headers. Initialized here:

**InitializeListView**

```
private void InitializeListView()
{
    // Set the view to show details.
    lbxBugged.View = View.Details;

    // Allow the user to rearrange columns.
    lbxBugged.AllowColumnReorder = true;

    // Select the item and subitems when selection is made.
    lbxBugged.FullRowSelect = true;

    // Display grid lines.
    lbxBugged.GridLines = true;

    // Sort the items in the list in ascending order.
    lbxBugged.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;

    // Attach Subitems to the ListView

    lbxBugged.Columns.Add("Code", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lbxBugged.Columns.Add("Description", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lbxBugged.Columns.Add("Author", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
}
```

**I've Tried:**

Originally using a **Listbox** but I've read that for multi column's then a listview must be used. So I've swapped to a listview but it does not populate the list. Not too sure which is the best way to go about this.

I've already initialized the listview so it shows the headers, I just need to know how to fill these spaces with the corresponding database information.

**populateListBox** (From when I was using a listbox, been researching but can only find people populating listviews with database information from an actual database and not a compact database.)

```
public void populateListBox()
{
    String query = "SELECT Bug_Code, Bug_Description, Bug_Author FROM tblBugs";
    SqlCeCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCeCommand(query, mySqlConnection);
    try
    {
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCeDataReader mySqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        lbxBugged.Items.Clear();
        while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            lbxBugged.Items.Add(mySqlDataReader["Bug_Code"].ToString() + "     " + mySqlDataReader["Bug_Description"].ToString() + "     " + mySqlDataReader["Bug_Author"].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (SqlCeException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error populating list box");
    }
}
```

Comment: A ListViewItem object has a SubItems collection property.

Comment: How would I go about doing this using SQL compact though?

Comment: I'm not sure why the SQL compact part is an issue.  `var lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[] { rdr["Bug_Code"].ToString(), rdr["Description"].ToString(), etc.});`

Comment: I've managed to write a new method and sort it out. I will post it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Thankyou LarsTech - helped a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First time using Listview so forgot to use items & subitems. Here is my finished method for anyone else struggling:

```
public void populateListView()
            {
                lbxBugged.Items.Clear();
                SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Bug_ID, Bug_Code, Bug_Description, Bug_Author FROM tblBugs ORDER BY Bug_ID ASC", mySqlConnection);

                try
                {
                    mySqlConnection.Open();
                    SqlCeDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr["Bug_ID"].ToString());
                        item.SubItems.Add(dr["Bug_Code"].ToString());
                        item.SubItems.Add(dr["Bug_Description"].ToString());
                        item.SubItems.Add(dr["Bug_Author"].ToString());

                        lbxBugged.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
                }


            }
```